# Easy Python: Number Guesser

Tags: python

I think this is easiest if I just give you the problem verbatim:

"Write a python program that continuously asks the user for a number other than 10. If 10 is entered, reprimand the user that they are not to guess the number 10."

I'm getting an error -- basically, I don't know how to define the guess variable before I enter the while loop.

```
target, guess = 10

while target != guess:
    guess = int(input('Enter a number other than 10: '))

print("Hey, you weren't supposed to enter 10!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is created because you are trying to assign two variables to one thing (the integer `10`).  If you want both of the variables to equal `10`, you need to do this:

```
target = guess = 10
```

However, in this program, you are not going to need that feature.  Instead, you will want something like this:

```
# Set target equal to 10
target = 10
# Make guess equal None, since there are no guesses yet
guess = None

# Loop until guess equals target
while target != guess:
    # Get new guess
    guess = int(input('Enter a number other than 10: '))

# Print message
print('Hey, you werent supposed to enter 10!')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a tuple to a tuple like this

```
target, guess = 10, 10
```

You don't acually want them to be the same because then the while loop exit immediately.

You could say

```
target, guess = 10, None
```

but usually it's clearer to write this over 2 lines

```
target = 10
guess = None
```

Another way is to avoid needing to assign a dummy value to guess in the first place

```
target = 10
while True:
    guess = int(input('Enter a number other than 10: '))
    if guess == target:
        break

print('Hey, you werent supposed to enter 10!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a variable "num" with value other than 10 (I have taken 11)
Then create a local variable as num and enter the values as u like and u will get the result

```
num=11
while num!=10:
      num=int(input("Enter a number other than 10"))
print "I thought i said no to 10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this...

```
condition = True

while condition == True:
  number = int(input("Enter a number"))
  if number == 10:
     print("You can't enter ten") #or whatever you want to say
  else:
    condition = False #if you want to drop out of the loop
```

hope this helps :)